# iOS Core Data - NSFetchRequest and NSPredicate not allowing double format?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I had a really weird bug when I tried to fetch a NSManagedObject with a certain attribute. Here's what I did :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == %@", LEVEL_NAME_KEY, _levelName];
```

In this example, `LEVEL_NAME_KEY = @"levelName"` and `_levelName` is a function parameter.
I wanted to do it that way so if I change my keys names, I can change it in the header by changing `LEVEL_NAME_KEY` only. But it doesn't work (it returns nothing when I execute the fetch).

However, when I write it that way :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"levelName == %@", _levelName];
```

Everything works fine and I get the correct NSManagedObject.

Anyone has an opinion on this? Is it a known bug and is there any solution for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format should be specified as:

```
@"%K == %@"
```

Because you need to differentiate between key names and parameter values (which get quoted when the predicate is created).

[Associated docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

Comment: Oh gosh, how did I missed that? Haha thank you really much for the link also ;)